# Inflating layout XML on Android

Tags: android, xml

I have error inflating button in XML. It's quite unique, among 10k users only couple of crashes. One for Android 9, another Android 8. Devices are Google Pixel 2l and Nexus 5x.

So I guess in general code is fine, but no ideas how to debug on specific devices.

Fatal Exception:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}:
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML
> file line #21: Error inflating class Button
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
```

This is the `Button`

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/navigation_back"
            android:onClick="backListener"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="@string/survey_register_driver"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </Button>
```

Comment: What is inside `@drawable/navigation_back`? Is that an image/icon or you have customises something?

Comment: It's just png file. Double checked each of them - all are valid ones: https://take.ms/o8Q5u